# Audio object is not playing in IE10

Tags: javascript, angularjs, audio, internet-explorer-10

I have AngualrJS app with a factory which responsible of playing audio in some events.
I have 3 different audio that created in that factory.
My issue is in IE10, that only one audio(message-sent) which I call from other controller is playing  the 3  and the other 2 is playing( calling from the same factory) only in debugger when I run step by step and after the first time playing then it's work as expected without debugger.
in Chrome and firefox it's works great.

```
var sounds = {
    messageSent: new Audio('/assets/audios/message-sent.mp3'),
    privateMessageRecived: new Audio('/assets/audios/private_message.mp3'),
    notificationRecieved: new Audio('/assets/audios/notification-recived.mp3')
};
```

Then it's play the audio :

```
sounds[soundName].play();
```

The mime-type is `audio/mpeg`.

```
    function start() {
        pusherEvents.onAll(function(channelName, eventName, data) {
            if (!isEmbedInactive() || isMuted()) {
                return;
            }

            switch (eventName) {
                case 'message':
                    if (!isMe(data.sender_id)) {
                        SpotsManager.getSpot({ id: data.spot_id })
                            .then(function(spot) {
                                if (spot.type === 'intimate') {
                                    sounds.privateMessageRecived.play();
                                }
                            });
                    }
                    break;
                case 'user_mentioned':
                    if (!isMe(data.mentioner.id)) {
                        sounds.notificationRecieved.play();
                    }
                    break;
                case 'message_liked':
                    var isMine = isMe(data.sender_id);
                    if (isMine) {
                        sounds.notificationRecieved.play();
                    }
                    break;
                case 'invitation_accepted':
                    if (!isMe(data.invitee.id)) {
                        sounds.notificationRecieved.play();
                    }
                    break;
                case 'intimate_user_invited':
                    sounds.notificationRecieved.play();
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past and was because `audio` tag was self closed.

try `<audio></audio>` and not `<audio/>`

It seems to be an IE10 bug

**update**

After some other information I suggest you to check the events that fires this Audio. Maybe that events doesn't work properly in IE10

Comment: The events fired in IE10 only when I debug it it's play the sound